# How to use threads using many web browsers

Tags: c#, browser

I'm working on an application and I want to create multiple threads, each thread must create a `WebBrowser`, every `WebBrowser` of these uses the method `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted`.

How can each of the created `WebBrowser` instances have it's own `DocumentCompleted` handler instead of the same `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted` method across all of them.

I explain :

in one case, an operation with a single web browser

```
int a = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    methode1();
}

private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (a == 1) methode2(wb);
    if (a == 2) methode2(wb);
}

public void methode1()
{
    webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.test.com");
    a = 1;
}

public void methode2()
{
    HtmlElement txt1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tesxtbox1");
    txt1.SetAttribute("value", "test");
    webBrowser.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
    a = 2;
}

public void methode3()
{
    webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.test3.com");
}
```

but if I want to make multiple operation, ie in butoon1 I add :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5  ;i++)
        methode1();
}
```

then to do it, I think I must have several webbrowser, so the solution is to create a thread for each operation

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5  ;i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(method1));
        thread.Start();
    }   
}
```

So each web browser created by a thread must have its own method `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted`, to not be confused between the results of other web browser.

or, use the same method `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted` for all created web browser, but the problem is how to specify which webbrowser, call the method webBrowser_DocumentCompleted.

Comment: When you create a WebBrowser object, you should be assigning the event handler to the DocumentCompleted handler, which then guarantees that each discrete WebBrowser instance knows what to do with itself when a document load has completed. You don't "direct" the handler to the "right" instance. That's backwards.

Comment: follow Hans Passant answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread

Answer (score 0):

You're not making several webbrowsers in your threads, you're still just using the one created somewhere you haven't told us.

Try actually make the webbrowser objects in the methode function

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                methode1();
        }

public void methode1()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wBrowser = System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            wBrowser.DocumentCompleted +=webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
            wBrowser.Navigate("http://www.test.com");
            a = 1;
        }
```

Also, you know you can check both values of a in the one if statement right?

```
if(a==1 || a==2)
     methode2(wb);
```